# FQL location_post, distance(latitude, longitude) returns inconsistent results

Tags: facebook-graph-api, location

I am querying the `location_post` like such:

```
SELECT id FROM location_post WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "37....","-122....")<100
```

In theory, that should return all `location_post` within 100 meters.

Doing so, I got 2 results.

However, when I increased the range to 1000, I got more results, but the previous 2 results are not two of them. Should I still get what I got with a smaller range when I increase the coverage?

Please tell me if I misunderstood something here.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Sometimes the results I get are 10 times the same one. 
Let me know if you found a way to resolve your problem.